# Get data from json in Scala

Tags: python, scala

I am trying to replicate this Python code in Scala:

```
import json

def test_json():
    parsed = json.loads("""[{"UserName":"user1","Tags":"one, two, three"},{"UserName":"user2","Tags":"one, two, three"}]""")
    tags = parsed[0]["Tags"].split(", ")
    print(tags)

test_json()
```

And I am coming up with this gibberish which does not work:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._

def testSix: Seq[String] = {
    val parsed = JSON.parseFull("""[{"UserName":"user1","Tags":"one, two, three"},{"UserName":"user2","Tags":"one, two, three"}]""")
    parsed.map(_ match {
        case head :: tail => head
        case _ => Option.empty
    }).map(_ match {
        case m: Map[String, String] => m("Tags").split(", ")
        case _ => Option.empty
    })
}
```

How can I get the `Tags` in the first entry of the json?

Comment: Which library are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov updated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a not good way to use the **raw scala JSON util** to parse **JSON**, it's not **type safe**. maybe you can [JSON4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) or other library.

And there is a way to achieve this by using **scala util**:

```
  def testSix: Seq[String] = {
    val parsed = JSON.parseFull("""[{"UserName":"user1","Tags":"one, two, three"},{"UserName":"user2","Tags":"one, two, three"}]""")
    val typedResult: Option[List[Map[String, String]]] = parsed.map {
      case a: List[_] => {
        a.map {
          case t: Map[String, String] => t
        }
      }
    }
    typedResult.map(_.flatMap(_.get("Tags")).toSeq).getOrElse(Seq())
  }
  testSix.head
```

Explanation:

1. parse json firstly
2. try to convert the **parsed result**(type: `Option[Any]`) to type: `Option[List[Map[String, String]]]`

Comment: Thanks, close, returns `List(one, two, three, one, two, three)`, but I need `List(one, two, three)`

Comment: `testSix.head.split(",\\s+").toList`

Answer (score 0):

First of all default `scala.util.parsing.json._` library might be ugly in this case, still try something as below

```
scala> val terriblyTraversedProperty = parsed.map(_ match { case  head :: tail => head case _ => Option.empty }).map(_ match { case firstUser: Map[String, String] => firstUser("Tags") case _ => Option.empty })
terriblyTraversedProperty: Option[java.io.Serializable] = Some(one, two, three)
```

To split the property which is `Option[String]`,

```
scala> val tags = terriblyTraversedProperty.map(_ match { case tagString: String => tagString.split(",").toList case _ => Option.empty[List[String]]} ).get
tags: Product with java.io.Serializable = List(one, " two", " three")
```

`tags` is `Product with java.io.Serializable` but is also an instance of `List[String]`

```
scala> tags.isInstanceOf[Seq[String]]
res35: Boolean = true
```

I can recommend scala [json4s](http://json4s.org/) library if you have freedom to choose libraries,

add `json4s` to build.sbt,

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" % "json4s-native_2.11" % "3.5.2"
```

example,

```
scala> import org.json4s._
import org.json4s._

scala> import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

scala> val parsed = parse("""[{"UserName":"user1","Tags":"one, two, three"},{"UserName":"user2","Tags":"one, two, three"}]""")
parsed: org.json4s.JValue = JArray(List(JObject(List((UserName,JString(user1)), (Tags,JString(one, two, three)))), JObject(List((UserName,JString(user2)), (Tags,JString(one, two, three))))))
```

**to get the property from first element**

```
scala> parsed.values.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]](0)("Tags")
res13: String = one, two, three
```

Comment: Thanks. The Some in `Some(one, two, three)` is what is killing me. I want `Seq[String]`. I can not change libraries unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, whenever you see `Some`, do `.map` :)

Comment: @delavnog See the answer, you will love it :)

Comment: Better, thanks, but this is not Seq[String], but java.io.Serializable. I really need a simple Seq[String]

Comment: Your json has `"one two three"` - that's a string. If you want seq, change that to `["one", "two", "three"]`.